# Unable to convert Streamz Kafka Stream to Dask Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, dask, dask-distributed

I am unable to convert the Streamz stream to Dask Stream which is generated using Kafka source.PFB code

```
from streamz import Stream
from streamz.dataframe import Random
from streamz.dataframe import DataFrame
import json
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
source = Stream.from_kafka(['logs'],
       {'bootstrap.servers': 'kafkaXX:9092',
        'group.id': 'streamz'}) 
source.scatter().map(json.loads).buffer(8).gather().sink(print)
source.start()
```

I am getting this error message

```
ValueError: Two different event loops active
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kafka source, if not otherwise instructed, will start its own event loop in a thread. The call to `Client()` also does this. To pass the loop from the one to the other, you can do

```
Stream.from_kafka(..., loop=client.loop)
```

Note that the call to `.scatter()` also needs explicit access to an event loop, but since this is dask-specific, it knows to use the loop of any client you have active.